# Missing Implicit return type when returning an Enum member in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Today I came across something interesting at work regarding the return type of a function when using Enum. I have tried to reproduce and make a simple example here.

```
const enum Fruits {
  Apple,
  Orange,
  Kiwi,
}

function getTest1() {
  return Fruits.Apple;
}

function getTest2(foo: boolean) {
  if (foo) {
    return Fruits.Orange;
  }

  return Fruits.Kiwi;
}

type test1ReturnType = ReturnType<typeof getTest1>;
type test2ReturnType = ReturnType<typeof getTest2>;
```

You can also play around with this example here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgMQE6IJZQjAbwCgYYBBABwoBs4AaEmAeQwEMwBzexgaWwHdsDAL5EiAM0RhgUbOBhcoAFTjQAjAAoAlIUYY4URBjDosuCADpKNOAG4ioiVJlyTildABMG8SBAAuGAAjP1p2HWJSbHEYHz8IxlJ9Q2NTHDwLFnYue1JHJIMjE0x0yz5Be0coAE8KOBgoVSg1ACVC4yVa+oBeGDaUsE66gB4aupAY9ya1AD57MfrGr36ioZ6+9sGu0a6JhQMPKE85oA)

As you can see I would expect the `test1ReturnType` to be `Fruits.Apple` since `test2ReturnType` is correctly typed as the union of `Fruits.Orange | Fruits.Kiwi`. This is not the case, and it is actually returning `Fruits`, which makes absolutely no sense.

Why isn't it returning the obvious? I know how that adding `as const` in the `getTest1` fn will fix this, but it shouldn't since `getTest2` is correctly typed.
I want to understand what's happening.

Comment: The compiler uses heuristics to decide whether or not to widen a literal type; see [ms/TS#10676](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676). Returning a single literal value from a function is widened because sometimes people subtype functions to return more stuff (see [comment](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676#issuecomment-244257359)); on the other hand, returning a union of literals is not widened, for other heuristic reasons. This has nothing to do with enums per se, you could reproduce with string literals like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXK1OW).

Comment: Does that address your question? If so I could flesh it out into an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey @jcalz thank you for the explanation, I have to say that it is really complete and I see that it is how it is, but I fail to see why widening when I'm not using classes is actually a good idea :_

Anyway, happy to have this as an answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Okay I'll write something up when I have a chance.  The heuristic rules are generally tuned to give good outcomes on average, even though there are obviously plenty of individual cases where they do an undesirable thing. I tend to agree that I'd rather see either all widening or no widening, but they test against a big corpus of real world code and presumably this minimized the number of breaking changes

Comment: Thanks @jcalz , I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey @jcalz, hope you don't mind me approaching you directly but I still show around to my colleagues the tremendous work you did on the answer to this question, so let me thank you for that again.

I just posted a similar but not so similar one and I was hoping to see if you could take a look or point me in the right direction to find some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634249/argument-of-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-union-of-string

I hope you don't find this too direct, I just really value your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue here is not specific to `enum`s.  It happens whenever you return a value of a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) from a function instead of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such types.  For example, here is the analogous behavior for string literals:

```
function foo() { return "a"; }
// function foo(): string

function bar() { return Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "z" };
// function bar(): "a" | "z"
```

The compiler uses heuristics to determine whether or not to widen a literal to its base type, based on assumptions of what behavior would most accurately conform to the expectations and desires of developers of real world code.  These rules are described in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), the PR that implemented this functionality.

For example, compare the inferred types in the following lines:

```
const x = "a"; // const x: "a"
let y = "a"; // let y: string
```

Here the type of `x` is inferred as the string literal type `"a"`, while the type of `y` is widened from `"a"` to `string`.  The reasoning behind this difference is that you can't change the value of a `const` variable, but you can change the value of a `let` variable.  The assumption is that the author of this code probably intends to change the value of `y` to some other `string`, otherwise they would have used `const`.

Of course heuristics are just heuristics; and they sometimes get things wrong. When the compiler's inference rules do something you don't like, your recourse is to express your intent explicitly, such as with a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables):

```
let z: "a" = "a"; // let z: "a"
```

---

Anyway, the specific situation you've run into is described in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676#issuecomment-244257359). The compiler assumes that few people intentionally write functions that return a single literal type.  A function implementation that always returns `"a"` or `Fruits.Apple` might plausibly be modified in the future to return a different `string` value or a different `Fruit` value... otherwise the author probably wouldn't have bothered making this a function in the first place.  So the return type is widened.  But if a function implementation returns a union of literal values, it's more likely that the author would be happy with the narrower type.

Again, this isn't always what people want, but is apparently close enough that it broke the least amount of real world code when this functionality was introduced.  If you are unhappy with it, your recourse is again to be more explicit, such as with a [return type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations):

```
function baz(): "a" {
    return "a";
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDARAQxQbhgehzUSWOALlQwCgAbAU1gE8lytd9aGzoAnASzAHMK1OjABeZdCiaTseGOzETKQgGYBXMMCg9wMFSBAAKAJQwA3jC501XMM2wBfCnPWbtu-UeOcovAao0tHTsAIzQuE3NLa1sYAFk0KAALADouNDAAExAAW0iAHhgABhSAVhgAfmYYCVEpB0xnfFcg3TCI72qAH1Q6gLdgmDDREyUpMwoYKeioGzsZCgcgA)

Comment: Amazing answer, super insightful and full of detail. This is premium content, thank you so much @jcalz